# Is it possible to return a break/ stop loop from function?

Tags: javascript, loops

I was wondering is it possible to return a "break" into a loop from a function;
Basically something like this:

```
var foo = function(n){
    if(n > 10 ){ return break; } 
    else{
        console.log(n);
    }
}
loop:
  for(var i = 0; i<1000000; i++){
      foo(i);
  }
```

Is it possible to stop the loop at `i=11` from within `foo()`? Can I somehow return a break, throw a break, pass a label of the loop and break it?
I guess this gets into exactly what break is and how it executes.

I know there are easy ways around this; I'm just trying to get a better understanding.
So basically """ Is it possible to break "loop" at 11 without doing any logic inside "loop" """

Comment: `"return break;"` ??? Or `return;`

Comment: replace `"return break;"` with something that actually breaks the loop;

Comment: `return "break"` probably ?

Comment: Return a bool and add that to the continue check on the loop   i < 1000000 && myBool.  Doesn't use a break but it will end the loop.

Comment: Check inside the loop for what your function has returned. If it is what you consider to be a break then break.

Comment: The for loop has the control - when you call `foo()` you're changing the execution context by placing arguments on the stack and jumping into the `foo` function - `foo()` has no knowledge about where it was called from.. and there's a good reason for this, typically a function is/can be called from many places...

I grew up as an assembly language programmer and in assembler you can do all kinds of weird "tricky Jake" programming constructs where jumping out of a loop from a function is possible - but as the assembly language programmer you're have the responsibility to clean up the stack

Comment: SO what you are saying is "no" ?

Comment: @lonewarrior556: You can't return *code* from a function.  But you can return a *value* which the loop would examine to execute code.  A boolean, an integer, whatever value you want to signal the loop.  Then the loop can either include that in its condition, or simply have an `if` which examines the value and executes a `break;`.

Comment: can I pass the loop label somehow( globally or as an argument ) and `break loop;` inside the function?

Comment: Loops don't have their own scope context, so I don't think you can pass it into the function itself.

Comment: @lonewarrior556: Still facing this issue? or solved? Was my answer helpful?

Comment: I think everyone should pay attention to what this question really asks for.

Comment: Josh KG hit it right with a comment, I'm not asking how to break a loop, but if it is possible to control the loop from within a different context.

Comment: @Neoheurist Make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I somehow return a break, throw a break, pass a label of the loop and break it? I guess this gets into exactly what break is and how it executes.

No, you cannot.

A function can only **`return`** a value or **`throw`** a value (or hang indefinitely, to be precise). There is no other way of leaving a function.

Labels work on the module, script and function body level. It's not possible to cross these boundaries with `break` or `continue` statements. Furthermore the grammar rules ensure that in every module, script or function

- no labelled statement contains another labelled statement with the same name
- no `break`/`continue` statement with a name occurs outside an appropriate labelled statement with that label name
- no unnamed `break`/`continue` statement occurs outside of an appropriate statement (e.g. loop or switch blocks)

Every violation of these rules is a syntax error.

That way, when the script/module/function body is executed and a `break` or `continue` statement is met somewhere, the control flow will be directed upwards, leaving the current statements, until the respective label is met. This labelled statement where the control flow then continues is necessarily within the same script/module/function.

As a reason for this, just think of `foo` being called not from inside your `loop:` loop but from some place outside of a labelled statement. Would this be a runtime error? At the point of calling `foo()`, or at the point of the `break`? Or would the `break` statement just continue if there was no label found with the respective name?

Comment: Thanks,. Although It feels weird being told "No you cannot do this" while working in javascript.

Comment: Well, you cannot do this any other sensible language that does not have `goto` :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use *break* like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    if(i > 10) break;
    console.log(i);
}
```

like this:

```
outside: for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
    inside: for(var j=0; j<100; j++) {
        if(i>10 && j>10) break;
        console.log(i, j);
    }
}
```

or like this:

```
bigger: {
    smaller: {
        if(i>10) break bigger;
    }
}
```

but you cann't do it like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
    (function(i){
        if(i > 10) break;
    })(i);
}
```

because the keyword *break* can only used in a loop, switch, or label statement that **a same scope inside**.

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = function(n){
   if(n > 10){ 
      return false;
   } 
   else{
    console.log(n);
    return true;
   }
}

for(var i = 0; i<1000000; i++){
  if (!foo(i)) break;
}
```

Try this code and see if it worked.

Comment: While this works, I think the OP is looking for a fuller explanation of how a function returns a value and how that value is evaluated within the context of a loop.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot return a 'break' but you can return a sentinel value that the loop knows to look for.  In the example below, if `foo(i)` returns a truthy value, the loop is ended:

```
var foo = function(n){
    if (n > 10) { 
        return true; 
    } 
    else{
        console.log(n);
    }
}

var breakLoop = false;
for(var i = 0; i<1000000 && !breakLoop; i++){
    breakLoop = !!foo(i);
}
```